Python + aiogram3 + sqlalchemy + БД sqlite. Не знаю как передать текст пользователя из handlers.py в requests.py
Вот хэндлер из handlers.py (который принимаем текст проблемы от пользователя и далее запрашивает контактный номер)
@router.message(Register.trouble_txt)
async def register_incident(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(trouble_txt=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Register.phone)
    await message.answer('Нажмите на кнопку, чтобы отправить\n'
                         ' номер телефона или укажите вручную', reply_markup=kb.get_phone)

И вот реквест из requests.py (Который должен по задумке принять написанный пользователем текст из хэндлера и сохранить в БД SQLite)
async def save_user_text(description: str):
    async with async_session() as session:
        new_entry = Other(description=register_incident)
        session.add(new_entry)
        await session.commit()

При старте кода крашится в циклическую ошибку:
ImportError: cannot import name 'register_incident' from partially initialized module 'app.handlers' (most likely due to a circular import)

Нейросети решить проблему не помогают, в сети тоже не нашел ответа.

Покажи импорты в файлах, скорее все где-то он циклится
